# How to automate source control in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension. Is it possible to tell Visual Studio Source Control to "checkout branch" or "stash changes". Performing those commands with "git.exe" is not enough as I need to know when Visual Studio has integrated the changes.

I've checked the Visual Studio SDK documentation but I can't find anything.

Comment: You can use `VersionControlServer` Class to do this. Since the stash change is new feature in VS2019, you can implement related functions by managing Shelveset. Please refer more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb171724(v=vs.120))

Comment: Thanks @PerryQian-MSFT, I'm going to explore that.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I've looked a bit at the `VersionControlServer` but it seems to be tricky to know when Visual Studio has integrated the changes. I've been told in the Roslyn gitter chat that it's pretty much impossible, and that the best bet is to use a delay.

Comment: Using a delay may be more likely to be implemented, it seems that `VersionControlServer` has no property that returns the time the change was committed, anyway, thanks for your tip.